# I can't query Firestore using a UIPickerView with 3 options

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, uipickerview

I'm trying to query Firestore using a UIPickerView with 3 fields and nothing is showing. If i comment-out 2 of the fields and run the query, i get results. Any idea what i'm missing or doing wrong. Please help.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
 if hospNameField.isFirstResponder {
     let itemselected = hospt[row]
     hospNameField.text = itemselected
 } else if teamNameField.isFirstResponder {
     let itemselected = team[row]
     teamNameField.text = itemselected
 } else if mdNameField.isFirstResponder {
     let itemselected = assignedmd[row]
     mdNameField.text = itemselected
 }
```

}

```
 @IBAction func getData(_ sender: Any) {
 if HOSP != (hospNameField.text!) {
     query = Firestore.firestore().collection(PTLIST_REF).whereField("hosp", isEqualTo: (hospNameField.text!))
 } else if TEAM != (teamNameField.text!) {
     query = Firestore.firestore().collection(PTLIST_REF).whereField("team", isEqualTo: (teamNameField.text!))
 } else if ASSIGNEDMD != (mdNameField.text!) {
     query = Firestore.firestore().collection(PTLIST_REF).whereField("assignedmd", isEqualTo: (mdNameField.text!))
     query.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
         if let err = error {
             debugPrint("error getting data: \(err)")
         } else {
             for document in (snapshot?.documents)! {
                 print(document.data())
             }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are missing a bracket. if you run the query you execute only the third if statement.You should close the last else if and then run the query.

Try this:

```
   @IBAction func getData(_ sender: Any) {
 if HOSP != (hospNameField.text!) {
     query = Firestore.firestore().collection(PTLIST_REF).whereField("hosp", isEqualTo: (hospNameField.text!))
 } else if TEAM != (teamNameField.text!) {
     query = Firestore.firestore().collection(PTLIST_REF).whereField("team", isEqualTo: (teamNameField.text!))
 } else if ASSIGNEDMD != (mdNameField.text!) {
     query = Firestore.firestore().collection(PTLIST_REF).whereField("assignedmd", isEqualTo: (mdNameField.text!))
}
     query.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
         if let err = error {
             debugPrint("error getting data: \(err)")
         } else {
             for document in (snapshot?.documents)! {
                 print(document.data())
             }
           }
       }
}
```

Comment: OMG! i missed that '}' thank you so much! i've been going around the same thing for the past 2 days!